# UnexpectedRollbackException - a full scenario analysis

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, exception

All I know about this exception is from Spring's [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/UnexpectedRollbackException.html) and some forum posts with frostrated developers pasting huge stack traces, and no replies.

From Spring's documentation:

> Thrown when an attempt to commit a transaction resulted in an unexpected rollback

I want to understand once and for all

1. **Exactly what causes it?**

   - Where did the rollback occur? in the App Server code or in the Database?
   - Was it caused due to a specific underlying exception (e.g. something from java.sql.*)?
   - Is it related to Hibernate? Is it related to Spring Transaction Manager (non JTA in my case)?
2. **How to avoid it?** is there any best practice to avoid it?
3. **How to debug it?** it seems to be hard to reproduce, any proven ways to troubleshoot it?

Comment: That particular exception is only thrown in certain specific circumstances, from within the Spring TX infrastructure. What message was contained within the `UnexpectedRollbackException`? That will help us track it down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scroll a little more back in the log (or increase it's buffer-size) and you will see what exactly caused the exception.

If it happens not to be there, check the `getMostSpecificCause()` and `getRootCause()` methods of `UnexpectedRollbackException`- they might be useful.

Comment: If the logs (with increased buffer size) contained the exact cause, I wouldn't have been asking it here. I want to understand the scenarios where this exception is thrown. Why is my setup relevant? a very common Hibernate + Spring configuration with HibernateTransactionManager by the way

Comment: it is a common mistake to skip the root cause of transaction rollbacks, because it's very far behind in the stacktrace, and there are sometimes sql queries outputted in between. I asked for your setup because otherwise I (or anyone else) can't guess what could actually be causing this. Anyway, check my updated answer for another hint.

Comment: @Bozho - +1 for update, to accept an answer though, I want to understand if the rollback occured in the database, or in the server (e.g. in the software transaction manager or in the database via a JDBC exception) maybe I'm not asking the right question?

Comment: well, eventually, by calling getRootCause() and getCause() (whichever is not null), you can reach the real root exception, which will tell you the details you want (hopefully).

Comment: Just used this in realtime, indeed scrolling up in the log does the trick :)

Comment: In my case I know the exact cause. It's because of bad data that my system is sourcing from another external system which I have no control over. So I would like to be able to catch this fucking exception and provide a proper exit path in my logic because it's leaving my data in an unexpected state. Not matter how many try catch-es I wrap my code, it still gets thrown. WHat the fuuck?

Answer (score 23):

I found this to be answering the rest of question: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-3452

> I guess we need to differentiate
>   between 'logical' transaction scopes
>   and 'physical' transactions here...
>
> What PROPAGATION_REQUIRED creates is a
>   logical transaction scope for each
>   method that it gets applied to. Each
>   such logical transaction scope can
>   individually decide on rollback-only
>   status, with an outer transaction
>   scope being logically independent from
>   the inner transaction scope. Of
>   course, in case of standard
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED behavior, they
>   will be mapped to the same physical
>   transaction. So a rollback-only marker
>   set in the inner transaction scope
>   does affect the outer transaction's
>   chance to actually commit. However,
>   since the outer transaction scope did
>   not decide on a rollback itself, the
>   rollback (silently triggered by the
>   inner transaction scope) comes
>   unexpected at that level - which is
>   why an UnexpectedRollbackException
>   gets thrown.
>
> PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW, in contrast,
>   uses a completely independent
>   transaction for each affected
>   transaction scope. In that case, the
>   underlying physical transactions will
>   be different and hence can commit or
>   rollback independently, with an outer
>   transaction not affected by an inner
>   transaction's rollback status.
>
> PROPAGATION_NESTED is different again
>   in that it uses a single physical
>   transaction with multiple savepoints
>   that it can roll back to. Such partial
>   rollbacks allow an inner transaction
>   scope to trigger a rollback for its
>   scope, with the outer transaction
>   being able to continue the physical
>   transaction despite some operations
>   having been rolled back. This is
>   typically mapped onto JDBC savepoints,
>   so will only work with JDBC resource
>   transactions (Spring's
>   DataSourceTransactionManager).
>
> To complete the discussion:
>   UnexpectedRollbackException may also
>   be thrown without the application ever
>   having set a rollback-only marker
>   itself. Instead, the transaction
>   infrastructure may have decided that
>   the only possible outcome is a
>   rollback, due to constraints in the
>   current transaction state. This is
>   particularly relevant with XA
>   transactions.
>
> As I suggested above, throwing an
>   exception at the inner transaction
>   scope, then catching that exception at
>   the outer scope and translating it
>   into a silent setRollbackOnly call
>   there should work for your scenario. A
>   caller of the outer transaction will
>   never see an exception then. Since you
>   only worry about such silent rollbacks
>   because of special requirements
>   imposed by a caller, I would even
>   argue that the correct architectural
>   solution is to use exceptions within
>   the service layer, and to translate
>   those exceptions into silent rollbacks
>   at the service facade level (right
>   before returning to that special
>   caller).
>
> Since your problem is possibly not
>   only about rollback exceptions, but
>   rather about any exceptions thrown
>   from your service layer, you could
>   even use standard exception-driven
>   rollbacks all the way throughout you
>   service layer, and then catch and log
>   such exceptions once the transaction
>   has already completed, in some
>   adapting service facade that
>   translates your service layer's
>   exceptions into UI-specific error
>   states.
>
> Juergen

Answer (score 5):

Well I can tell you how to reproduce the UnexpectedRollbackException. I was working on my project, and I got this UnexpectedRollbackException in following situation. I am having controller, service and dao layers in my project.
What I did is in my service layer class,

```
class SomeServiceClass {
    void outerTransaction() {
        // some lines of code
        innerTransaction();
        //AbstractPlatformTransactionManager tries to commit but UnexpectedRollbackException is thrown, not here but in controller layer class that uses SomeServiceClass.
    }

    void innerTransaction() {
        try {
            // someDaoMethod or someDaoOperation that throws exception
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // when exception is caught, transaction is rolled back, outer transaction does not know about it.
            // I got this point where inner transaction gets rolled back when I set HibernateTransactionManager.setFailEarlyOnGlobalRollbackOnly(true)
            // FYI : use of following second dao access is wrong, 
            try {
                // again some dao operation
            } catch(Exception e1) {
                throw e2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Spring Framework 4 + Java 1.8 for this exception.
I solved it.

I know that runtime exceptions rollbacks.
But in my case, project do not use runtime exceptions.

For example, we have code.

```
@Transactional 
@Service
UserFacadeIml implements UserFacade
{
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

//throws  UnexpectedRollbackException 
//instead NotRuntimeEx
@Override
public void saveUser(User user)
throws NotRuntimeEx
{
 return userService.saveUser(user);
}
}
```

I solved it, when add "Transactional(rollBackFor=NotRuntimeEx.class)" for facade.
It works, because Spring use proxy for facade and proxy for service.
When transactional rollback, proxy of service send context to facade.
But facade proxy does not understand, why transaction rollback.

```
@Transactional(rollBackFor=NotRuntimeEx.class)
@Service
UserServiceIml implements UserService
{
@Override
public void saveUser(User user)
throws NotRuntimeEx
{
 throw new NotRuntimeEx(user);
}
}
```

Comment: What is ```NotRuntimeEx```, checked or unchecked? Your answer is not complete

Comment: @TheRealChx101 it's implicit in the answer... it's quite clear that NotRuntimeEx is a checked Exception

Comment: @Gamby No it's not. But I'll take your word for it.