# Exception on batch processing UnexpectedRollbackException - Transaction rolled back

Tags: java, spring

I am getting the below exception when doing a batch processing

```
encountered an error.org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
```

Could someone help me with what might be the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007097/unexpectedrollbackexception-a-full-scenario-analysis

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace, especially the 'caused by' part.

Comment: can u show the complete debug statement ?

Comment: can you show framework log?

Comment: The times I've gotten this error (wasn't using Spring Batch) it was because I was catching an exception from the database (in this case, an optimistic lock exception) and then retrying the operation without closing and restarting the transaction.  Anytime the database or JPA layer throws an exception you MUST close and reopen the transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The possibility of getting this exception in Spring-managed environments is when the transaction propagation is set to `REQUIRED`:

```
<tx:method name="do*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
```

Consider a scenario as this:

> Caller -------> [Transactional Method1(m1)] ----------> [Transactional
>   Method2(m2)]

In Spring-managed environments, there is a difference between `logical` and `physical` transactions. A `logical` transaction scope is created for each method upon which this setting is applied. The `logical` transaction scope for method `m1` is different from `m2`. Each `logical` transaction can determine its own rollback-only status individually. And with this setting, an outer transaction scope (m1's scope) is logically independent from the inner transaction scope (m2's scope).

But all these scopes are mapped to the same `physical` transaction. So, if the inner transaction is marked for rollback, it effects the outer transaction's chance to commit (even if there is no exception thrown from the the outer transaction).

Now if there is an exception thrown from inner transaction and it is marked for rollback. But there is no exception thrown from outer transaction, so it has not decided on the rollback itself, and so the rollback (silently triggered by the inner transaction scope) is unexpected. And a corresponding `UnexpectedRollbackException` is thrown at that point.

So if an inner transaction (of which the outer caller is not aware) silently marks a transaction as rollback-only, the outer caller receives an `UnexpectedRollbackException` if it still calls commit. This is an indication to the outer caller that a rollback was performed instead of a commit. And this an expected behavior to let the caller of a transaction know that there was an exception and the the transaction was rolled back.

Answer (score 7):

Probably you have a checked exception somewhere in one of your beans that you catch in another one, but the transaction advice of spring notices it and will mark the transaction for rollback.

You can play with the noRollBackFor property of the Transactional annotation.