# Prevent transaction rollback when catching AccessDeniedException in inner service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have 2 services: `RecentRecordService` and `BookService`.

```java
@Service
public class RecentRecordService {
    @Transactional
    public List<Book> getRecentReadBooks() {
        List<Long> recentReadBookIds = getRecentReadBookIds();
        List<Book> recentReadBooks = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Long bookId : recentReadBookIds) {
            try {
                Book book = bookService.getBook(bookId);
                recentReadBooks.add(book);
            } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
                // skip
            }
        }

        return recentReadBooks;
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class BookService {
    @Transactional
    public Book getBook(Long bookId) {
        Book book = bookDao.get(bookId);
        if (!hasReadPermission(book)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException(); // spring-security exception
        }
        return book;
    }
}
```

Assume that `getRecentReadBookIds()` returns `[1, 2, 3]`.

When the session user has permission for all the book IDs that returned from `getRecentReadBookIds()`, everything works fine. `getRecentReadBooks()` will return a list of 3 `Book`s.

Suddenly, the owner of book #2 changed the permission setting of it from "Public" to "Private". Therefore, the session user can no longer read the book #2.

I was expecting that `getRecentReadBooks()` will return a list of 2 `Book`s, which contains the info of book #1 and book #3. However, the method failed with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
```

After some research, I found that it has something to do with the transaction propagation. The transation will be marked as "rollback-only" even if I use try-catch to handle the `AccessDeniedException` in `getRecentReadBooks()`.

This problem seems to be solved by changing the `@Transactional` annotation for `getBook()` into:

```java
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
    public Book getBook(Long bookId) {
        // ...
    }
```

or

```
    @Transactional(noRollbackFor = AccessDeniedException.class)
    public Book getBook(Long bookId) {
        // ...
    }
```

However, I was wondering if I can solve the problem by only modifying `RecentRecordService`. After all, `RecentRecordService` is the one who wants to handle `AccessDeniedException` on its own.

Any suggestion will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html)

> By default, a transaction will be rolling back on RuntimeException and
>   Error but not on checked exceptions (business exceptions)

[AccessDeniedException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDeniedException.html) is a subclass of RuntimeException

If in your case the AccessDeniedException used is the spring frameworks , and as per the requirement if the exception on access denied can be made a custom business exception (not a subclass of Runtime Exception ) , it should work without annotating getBook(Long bookId) method.

**Update**

OP decided to fix the root cause . This is to provide the rationale behind my answer for any future references

> AccessDeniedException : Thrown if an Authentication object does not
>   hold a required authority.

As per my understanding , here the access to a book is based on business logic and not user role specific. A custom business exception would be apt in such a scenario.

Comment: Thank you, but I knew that AccessDeniedException is a subclass of RuntimeException. No, I can't make the exception to a checked exception. What I want to know is a way to solve the problem with only modifying RecentRecordService.

Comment: You may need to identify the root cause and fix it probably : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2007165/4214241

Comment: I think I know the root cause. I just need a proper fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to solve it by only modifying the `RecentRecordService` because the transaction is already marked as rollback in the `BookService` due to a `RuntimeException` happens in it. And once the `TransactionStatus` is marked as rollback , there is no way to revert it to not rollback currently.

So , you have to make `BookService#getBook()` does not mark the transaction as rollback by :

```java
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public Book getBook(Long bookId) {

}
```

which means the transaction will not marked as rollback no matter what exception happen. It makes sense to do it as this method is supposed to be read-only , so it is no point to rollback when a method is not supposed to modify anythings.

Comment: If I want to make `BookService#getBook()` unmodified, does it make sense if I write a wrapper class for it, say `BookServiceWrapper#getBook()` and make the wrapper method as `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = Throwable.class)`?

Comment: it should not work if you just use a wrapper to wrap the `BookService#getBook()` but keep `BookService#getBook()` unchanged because it will still mark the transaction as rollback if exception happen in it.

Comment: How about making the wrapper method as `@Transactional(Propagation.NESTED)`?